# rx-java2: repeat Maybe/Flowable unless empty

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

In rx-java2 there is Maybe.repeat()/Flowable.repeat() operator. But if Maybe/Flowable is empty, it just resubscribes to it indefinitely and emitts neither values nor completion status.
How can I resubscribe only if previous subscription did emit something?

In projectreactor the repeatWhen() operator can be used:

```
someMono.repeatWhen { it.takeWhile { i -> i > 0 } }
```

But in rx-java2 this operator does not work this way. So currently I emit an error if Maybe is empty, and then recover from this error:

```
someMaybe
  .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.error(MyStopException()))
  .repeat()
  .onErrorResumeNext { th: Throwable ->
    if (th is MyStopException)
      Flowable.empty()
    else
      Flowable.error(th)
  }
```

Is there any better/more natural way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For the `Maybe` case, you could do something like:

```
someMaybe
    .flatMapPublisher(value ->
        Flowable.just(value).repeat()
    )
    .subscribe(...);
```

This way, if `someMaybe` is empty, then `Flowable.just(value).repeat()` is not invoked.

For the Flowable case, you can do something like:

```
    AtomicBoolean empty = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    someFlowable
        .doOnNext(value -> empty.set(false))
        .repeatWhen(completed ->
          completed.takeUntil(__ -> { return empty.get(); })
        )
        .subscribe(...);
```

There's probably a better way, but I couldn't think of any other way that doesn't involve implementing a custom operator.